# Modify this query formula to include additional columns

Tags: google-sheets

```
=unique(ArrayFormula(regexreplace(query(query(regexreplace(uploadData!D:D,"\(|\)",""),"where not(Col1) matches '"&JOIN("|", regexreplace(filter(settingsDoNotInclude!A:A, len(settingsDoNotInclude!A:A)), "\(|\)",""))&"'"),"Select * where Col1 <>'' and Col1 <>'#VALUE!'"), "^(\d+)\s","($1) ")))
```

I have this query formula which filters our call log (`uploadData!D:D`) and removes any phone numbers listed in `settingsDoNotInclude!A:A`. However, I want to include data from `uploadData!H:H`, `uploadData!I:I` and `uploadData!M:M (Date, Time and Duration information)` with the results.

Here's a link to the sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T_TyzfUb7spZ9DSfuuY-CNkbH12FlOh5xxoCiw3kv58/edit#gid=0

The phone numbers have been randomly generated and are not real.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=ArrayFormula( vlookup(filter(uploadData!D:D, isna(match(uploadData!D:D, settingsDoNotInclude!A2:A13, 0))), {uploadData!D:D, uploadData!A:M}, {5,9,10, 14}, 0))
```